# How do I limit the radius that a say command can be seen from?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have an adventure map with a say command that activates after a certain mob is killed. This can be problematic, because if you die while fighting the mob, it sends you to a town, and automatically makes the difficulty set to peaceful. This in turn kills the mob and sets off the say command without the player actually killing it. With this situation, can I make a say command that is only seen by players that are within a certain radius? I do not want a say command that is only set off when a player enters a certain radius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't specify a radius for the command `/say`. You should learn json and use `/tellraw` instead. If you want to send the message to everyone within a radius of 100 blocks, do `/tellraw @a[r=100]`.

Basic JSON formatting:
`/tellraw @a[r=100] {text:"Hello world!"}`

With colours: `/tellraw @a[r=100] {text:"Hello world!",color:"aqua"}`

These colours have different names than wool colours, for example cyan is `dark_aqua`. These names can be found on the Minecraft wiki [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Formatting_codes).

You can do lots more with JSON than you can do with /say. Check out this awesome json generator: https://www.minecraftjson.com/

Comment: You could also just leave the JSON if you don't need anything like colours or click events, for example `/tellraw @a[r=100] "Hello everyone that is in a radius of 100 blocks from me!"`

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `distance=..100` instead of `r=100`